# How to handle Facebook Android SDK v4.1 Access Token between Activities

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

When i go to another activity after successfully logged a user in i can't access to the Facebook Access token

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
```

I got this in the LogCat:

```
{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}
```

Comment: My solution if you are using the android login button, is to use a fragment and call it inside every activity, you can choose to disply it or not depending on what the current activity will be doing, all methods will work just fine.

Comment: I'm not using the login button just registering the callback, how can you implement the fragment?

Comment: I just posted some code so you can see how I l handling it dont forget to add the face book activity in your manifest file, it should work form any activity. let me kow if you have any question. if you find my answer helpfull please validate it.

Comment: Thank you AnixPasBesoin ill try the code and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution if you are using the android login button is:
To use a fragment and call it inside every activity, you can choose to display it or not depending on what the current activity will be doing, all the fragment's methods will work just fine.

Here is some code:

```
package com.infoplusplus.anix.currentapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


/**
 * Created by Anix on 09/04/2015.
 */
public class LoginFacebookFragment extends Fragment {
    public LoginFacebookFragment() {
    }

    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;
    private AccessTokenTracker tokenTracker;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        tokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
            }
        };
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                if (newProfile != null) {
                    //TODO the user has logged out
                } else {
                   //TODO the user may have logged in or changed some of his profile settings
                }
            }
        };
        profileTracker.startTracking();
        tokenTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_facebook, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //TODO, implement onSuccess
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //TODO, implement onCancel
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            //TODO, implement onError inorder to handle the errors
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_facebookLogin);
        //TODO: get some more permissions from the user
        //loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        profileTracker.startTracking();
        tokenTracker.startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
        tokenTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tokenTracker.stopTracking();
        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Anix, i've tried the code in a fragment login process its fine, im calling the fragment in another activity but i still can't access the Access Token.

Comment: Have you check you configured everything fine, the hashkey...?

Comment: Yes i have double check everything and its fine, in the activity and fragment where im doing the login process i do have access to the token but when i try to use it in another activity even with your solution i can't.

Comment: have you thought using a singleton class? store the access token it that class and then retrieve it?

Comment: No i haven't... if you can help me with some code that would be very nice.

Comment: About the singleton it did work, just one question... do you think its safe to store the Facebook access token in a singleton?

Comment: My guess would be its not, cause the acces token might change he safest way is to use a custom app (extend a new class from the class Application) ans use this class a singleton, and track your access token with it, I ve never implemented it, so sorry i have no code to show, but start with digging in custom appliation it will help you, in case my answer helped you please validate it.

Comment: can you guys give me some code , that how you managed it to get the access token , using singelton class or what else is safe. I have the same situation as described in the question , Please help